# $X$ is Hausdorff, $G$ is a finite group prove that $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to start this off by saying I've seen the other questions that are identical to this one, but I didn't really understand the suggestions given in those.

So the question states: Let $G$ act continuously on $X$ i.e the map $G\times X\to X$ sending $(g,x)\mapsto gx$ is continuous. Then define an equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if and only if there exists a $g\in G$ such that $gx=y$. Then give $X/\sim :=X/G$ the quotient topology. Show that if $X$ is Hausdorff and $G$ is finite then $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

I have my attempt bellow, however I am stuck on the last part where I want to show $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. I'm not really sure how to come to a conclusion.

> Choose two orbits, $Gx\neq Gy$, then we have
> $x\neq y$. Define $U_g$ and $V_g$ to be open neighbourhoods of $gx$
> and $gy$ respectively, such that $U_g\cap V_h=\emptyset$ for all
> $h,g\in G$, which we can do as $X$ is Hausdorff and $gx\neq hy$ as
> they are in different orbits. Now consider all the sets $p(U_g)$ and
> $p(V_g)$, I claim that $U=~\bigcap_{g\in G}p(U_g)$ and
> $V=\bigcap_{g\in G}p(V_g)$ are disjoint neighbourhoods of
> $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{y}$ (The equivalence classes of $x$ and $y$ respectively).
>
> Since each $p(U_g)$ and $p(V_g)$ are open by Lemma 2 (Lemma 2 just
> says $p$ is an open map), furthermore $U$ and $V$ are finite
> intersections of these open sets, as $G$ is finite, we have that they
> are open in $X/G$. $U$ certainly contains $\overline{x}$ as each $U_g$
> contains $gx$ for some $g\in G$ which is equivalent to $x$, and with
> an identical argument $V$ contains $\overline{y}$. Suppose for a
> contradiction that $U\cap V$ is non-empty, take an element
> $z\in~U\cap~V$ then $z\in p(U_g)$ and $z\in p(V_g)$ for each $g\in G$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $X/G$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal $\Delta$ of $X/G \times X/G$ is closed. Since $p$ is an open quotient map, $p\times p$ is also a quotient map, so it suffices to prove that $(p\times p)^{-1}(\Delta)$ is closed in $X\times X$.

Comment: The trick for concluding your argument is to make a more "explicit" construction of $U_{g}$ and $V_{h}$. As a matter of fact, you can choose open subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $x\in A$, $y\in B$ and $g\cdot A \cap B=\emptyset$ for every $g$. Your desired open sets are $p(A)$ and $p(B)$.

Comment: So just checking your first comment is an alternative proof? Then for the second one is $g\cdot A\cap B$ the same as $(g\cdot A)\cap(g\cdot B)$ so $A$ and $B$ contain no elements that are in the same orbit, something like this?

Comment: I think that they are not the same. But yes, it'd be an alternative proof (the method is pretty much the same).

Comment: The reason for the first comment is that the "closedness" argument is valid for a more general type of actions, called "proper actions". This is the finite version, and the discrete version is sometimes named "properly discontinous" (even though the action is by definition continuous...)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks so much for the answer by the way it really helped!

Comment: No problem! I find that group actions are always very helpful in topology and geometry, so it's always nice to see people studying them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Gx\neq Gy$. The argument is very similar to what you have done so far!

Take $g\in G$. Since $g\cdot x \neq y$, there are open sets $U_{g},V_{g}$ such that $g\cdot x\in U_{g}$, $y\in V_{g}$ and $U_{g}\cap V_{g}=\emptyset$. Now choose the following open subsets:

$$
U=\bigcap_{g\in G}g^{-1}U_{g}, V=\bigcap_{g\in G}V_{g}.
$$

Since $G$ is finite and left translations are homeomorphisms, $U$ and $V$ are open neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$. Notice that, for every $g$, $gU\cap V=\emptyset$.

Now, choose $p(U)$ and $p(V)$. We only need to prove that $p(U)\cap p(V)=\emptyset$.

Let $p(z)\in p(U)\cap p(V)$, so that $p(z)=p(a)=p(b)$ for some $a\in U$, $b\in V$. Therefore, for some $h\in G$, $b=ha\in V\cap hU$, which is a contradiction.

Hope this helps!