# What if a group action on a smooth manifold is proper, smooth BUT not free?

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, quotient-spaces

For simplicity, let $G$ be a finite group with discrete topology and $M$ be a smooth manifold.

Suppose that $G$ acts on $M$ smoothly. Then, it is kind of trivial to see that the action of $G$ is proper.

However, I further assume that $G$ does NOT act freely on $M$. That is, there exists some $g (\neq e_G) \in G$ and a point $p \in M$ such that $g \cdot p =p$.

Then, can I still define the quotient space $M/G$ as some kind of a manifold?

If I remember right, $M/G$ is NOT Hausdorff. Nevertheless, is $M/G$ still locally Euclidean and given a smooth structure in lieu with the projection map $\pi : M \to M/G$?

The link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold somewhat gives hope to me in this aspect, but I cannot judge on my own..

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: If a finite group $G$ acts on a Hausdorff topological space $M$, then the quotient $M/G$ is always Hausdorff. Here is a sketch of the proof: Suppose $O_1,O_2\in M/G$. Take $x\in O_1$. For each $y\in O_2$, there is a neighbourhood that separate $x$ from $y$. Take the intersection of all of them ($O_2$ is finite so the intersection is still an open set) and call it $U_x$. Do the same for a fixed point $y\in O_2$ which results in a neighbourhood $U_y$. Then $U_x, U_y$ separate $O_1$ and $O_2$ in $M/G$.

Comment: Apparently what I said was already asked on this site before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061459/x-is-hausdorff-g-is-a-finite-group-prove-that-x-g-is-hausdorff

Comment: Oh I see...then is it possible to give $M/G$ some kind of a smooth manifold structure? I do not assume any linearity or faithfulness in the action, so I cannot employ the notion of "orbifold"...  So, I just want to stick to the formalism of manifold for my problem.

Comment: I cannot think of a reference right now but if I am not mistaken, the quotient is still a manifold but possibly not a smooth manifold.

Comment: @Levent: No, the quotient need not be a topological manifold.

Comment: Could you recommend me any reference?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example of a smooth finite group action such that the quotient space is not a topological manifold is
$$
M={\mathbb R}^3, G\cong {\mathbb Z}_2,
$$
and the generator $g$ of $G$ acts on $M$ by
$$
g({\mathbf x})= -{\mathbf x}.
$$
The quotient space $M/G$ is homeomorphic to the (open) cone over ${\mathbb R} P^2$, hence, is not a topological manifold.

Comment: If you take $M = \mathbb{R}$, then $M/(x \sim -x) \cong [0, 1)$ is only a manifold *with boundary*.

Comment: @ronno: Right, I was aiming for something which is not a manifold with boundary.